# Shortcut keys on ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, contextmenu, keyboard-shortcuts

Hello i have added ContextManuStrip to TreeList. ContextManuStrip has some ToolStripMenuItems, i have implemented their "Click" events and everything works fine. Now in designer i added "ShortcutKeys". Now, how to do so: when i use shortcut key - program will call my "Click" event..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done automaticaly, program calls this event when shortcut key is clicked.